# Ionic 3 firebase display data error

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Currently I am able to post data to the firebase, but I can't get the data and display it in my ionic 3 app. This is my shoes.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-shoes',
  templateUrl: 'shoes.html',
})
export class ShoesPage {
  shoppingItems: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  newItem = '';

  getShoppingItems() {
    return this.afDB.list('/shoppingItems/');
  }
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
public afDB: AngularFireDatabase){
    this.addItem("awesomeStuff");
    this.getShoppingItems();
    alert(this.shoppingItems);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ShoesPage');
  }


  addItem(name) {
    this.afDB.list('/shoppingItems/').push(name);
  }

  removeItem(id) {
    this.afDB.list('/shoppingItems/').remove(id);
  }
}
```

This is a part of my the shoes.html file:

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">
      {{item.$value}}
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Any ideas how I can be able to display the firebase data? Currently I am getting: [object Object] when I alert the shoppingList.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find out what is going on?